# Which is latest C++ Standard Release , From where i can download it

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find the current {X} standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-x-standard)

I have a simple Question !

I am looking for soft copy of latest C++  Standard release. I have ISO/IEC 14882 First Edition ,1998-09-01, But i have doubt if it is latest.

I visited http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/, There are many drafts.

Please  guide me which  one is latest and i should refer.

Comment: Wow, this is not something I usually see here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-x-standard#83763

Comment: Thanks all , yes i found it is duplicate, But could not found in my initial search ..Thanks

Comment: According to [this](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) site: "As of November 2011, the LaTeX source of the draft standard is being actively maintained publicly at GitHub. Check out the repo to get the current snapshot, or any previous version in the history." PDF of the latest working draft is also available on the [same site](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to pay money, you can always use the final draft.  It is basically the same with only minor edits.  And it is free.

You can find a PDF [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/CS/C++draft/ISO-CPP-body.pdf).  Otherwise just search for 14882 final draft.

edit: Updated link to the document instead of the index

Answer (score 1):

The current standard is from 2003 (the numbers don't change with revisions, i.e. it's still ISO/IEC 14882). The standard isn't free, you have to buy it or perhaps borrow it from a library if you want to read it.

Comment: I have some doubts, I need to clarify , So i need to search a library first :)

Comment: Or you can post a question on this site. Surely, someone will answer and cite the relevant portions of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is that released versions of the C++ standard aren't (at least legally) available for free. The good news is that as reference books go, the [C++ Standard](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882-2003) is rather on the inexpensive side -- $30 US at the present time.

If you want to find out about the next standard, the current draft is [N2960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2960.pdf), a free download.

Edit: It's worth noting that while the standard was updated in 2003, the changes in that case were mostly pretty minimal. Virtually none really changed the real definition of the language itself. Probably the single largest technical change was to require that std::vector use contiguous storage. This wasn't originally required, but every known implementation did it anyway, so it just turned how things were anyway into a requirement. Unless your question is *really* arcane, chances are pretty good that the standard you have is entirely adequate.

Comment: I was under the impression that TR1 was fairly significant - but maybe you don't regard that as part of the 2003 standard (with probably some justification).

Comment: TR1 is fairly significant, but I don't consider it part of the standard -- and the committee doesn't either. Oddly enough, there are actually *two* TR1's, but each is considered an independent entity, not part of the standard to which it applies. Most of the more recent TR1 (i.e. essentially everything but the random number generators) was/will be incorporated into C++ 0x though.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#machine-readable-standard).